Which movie contains a bored hired killer?
I'm trying to remember which movie is it from.. There's a hired killer that's super rich and super bored, he brags to his girl about some yoga achievement and goes on to kill someone for a dime, literally. I think his exact words are 'only a few people in the world can do that yoga position' or something along the lines.

It is Faster (2010).
Plot:

An ex-con sets out to avenge his brother's death after they were double-crossed during a heist years ago. During his campaign, however, he's tracked by a veteran cop and an egocentric hit man.

The hit man (Oliver Jackson-Cohen) lives in an expensive house with his girl friend, seems he's very rich and there's this scene during his introduction in the movie where he's in a very complicated yoga pose.
check this video.



He brags about his yoga abilities to his girlfriend like this.

l did a sequence of poses
  this morning that only 10 people
  on the planet can do.

